# Use BeautifulSoup open .gz file in sitemap.xml

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, gzip

I'm using beautifulsoup to build data from a website. I need to first grab all `.gz` files from `sitemap.xml` website.

I did:

```
def getGz():
    http = httplib2.Http()
    status, response = http.request('url/sitemap.xml)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    links = soup.find_all("loc")
```

Then I have all `.gz` files' url but with `<loc>` out side. How can I get rid of `<loc>`?

What I have now:

```
<loc>url/sitemap-samples-0.xml.gz</loc>
```

I want to get rid of `<loc>` and then open `.gz` file.

And, how can I open `.gz` files from internet and get the information in it by using python?

Comment: Doing a `.get_text()` on each of the links should get rid of the `<loc>` tags.

Comment: Please change your question title to more descriptive and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get just the url like so using list comprehension:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def getGz():
    #http = httplib2.Http()
    #status, response = http.request('url/sitemap.xml')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    links = [loc.text for loc in soup.find_all("loc")]
```

Then you have to download the gz file and open it using `gzip`, or read the gz file into a StringIO object and use that `StringIO` object for `gzip.open`